# Endian safe conversion of two chars to unsigned short

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am working with a function that takes two `char`s, representing an unsigned 16 bit integer, as arguments. I need to convert these values back to an unsigned integer and I would like the method to be endian-safe. I have come up with the method below but I'd like to know if there is a better way. I'm using Qt so the final value is stored in a `quint16`.

```
char msb; // most significant byte
char lsb; // least significant byte
quint16 value = ((msb & 0xff) << 8) | (lsb & 0xff);
```

Comment: You don't need to concern yourself with endian-ness unless you're working with pointers to non-char basic types or external data.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee It's external data coming from a little endian machine

Comment: You should be using `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` especially when bit shifting.

Comment: You don't need & 0xff.

Comment: Why are you ANDing an 8-bit quantity with 0xff?  Seems redundant.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I'm still learning the bitwise operations. As for making them unsigned. I'm cleaning up someone else's parser class but I think I could change that without creating problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<QtEndian>` functions.  In your case, you could use qFromLittleEndian.  It is a template function, so you don't need to pass chars into a function, just a quint16 and it will return a host-endian version of that quint16.  When responding, you could just call qToLittleEndian.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about those functions